# No search in official doxygen documentation?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I was wondering how I can do something with doxygen so I tried to find out on the official doxygen site at https://doxygen.nl. As none of the topics seemed to help, I thought I would use search to find what I need but no matter how I looked or turned of privacy features or changed browsers (FF, Chrome), I could not find a search bar at all. Is it really possible that Doxygen does not enable the search function in its own documentation?

Comment: Indeed in the user manual doxygen disabled the search engine and also the complete layout of the page has been changed by means of the `doxygen_manual.css`.

Comment: Are you  thinking about the normal doxygen search or ... ? The normal doxygen search will be hard, but in the doxygen documentation in pdf there is al least an index of a number of keywords.

Comment: I am thinking of the normal doxygen search, one of the first three options described here:
https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/searching.html

Comment: I now had a quick look, but with the current keywords that would be linked it wouldn't make sense (it are just the names of the chapters / paragraphs that would be shown).